# Fetch and process external data periodically?

Tags: c#, process, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET website using ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

I need to read data from an external web-service that exposes a `GetTransaction(DateTime startDate)` function.
This returns data about the recent transactions that occurred since the requested date.

I want to make in my website a 'service' that sequentially (every `x` minutes), collects the recent transactions from the web-service and sets up data in my website's data-store accordingly.

What technique is recommended?
Should I use Windows Workflow Foundation?

I'm planning to host my website on Windows Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shimmy, doing this is very simple with Quartz.Net or Hangfire.

The problem is due to IIS that goes down every some time, by default 20 minutes. If your site have heavy traffic it could not be a problem, but in cloud it could be a big problem since you cannot define witch instance need to run this job.

Maybe you can go with [Azure Web Jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) that you configure pointing to an endpoint that does the work or with [Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/) that has Web Jobs too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I **am** planning to host it on Azure. I'll check about Web Jobs.

Comment: I think web-jobs is what I'm looking for, although I don't like the idea so much since it's Azure-specific, but I can still live with it. Question is if it's possible to access the same DB from multiple apps (both the website and the console app web-job).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The webjob is just a console application and it can whatever the webapp can do

Comment: I don't think that is possible to access database from a WebJob, looks like it's just a trigger to call a URI at a specific schedule.

The way I use is to schedule to call that URI and the method that is called check DB to see if have any work to do.

You can do this way and do not get sticky with Azure, you can try Parse.com with the same schedule capabilities for example or use any Web monitoring service, but in that case you'll need to control your schedule on the other side.

Comment: @Luiz sure it's possible. I can make a client console app that accesses the DB, unless it won't work. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Shimmy as I saw the client console app is only to use with SDK and not some code that is run when the Job is triggered. But I never used and maybe could be wrong, if you can do this, please let me know.

Comment: So maybe should I just integrate it as a middleware inside my app? It's a time based process, meaning, I mark my completion date internally, then the upcoming request is from that date, so one of the servers is down, I start on from last successful end-date.

Comment: @Shimmy, as your explained your application should receive a call and start to processing by steps. 1. Check if need to process. 2. Process. 3. Mark date processed. Your external Schedule don't need to know anything, just trigger this process.